# The component is not updating in React useState

Tags: reactjs

```
const movieList = getMovies();

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650,
  },
});

const Movie = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setMovies(movieList);
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = (movie) => {
    deleteMovie(movie._id);
    setMovies(movies);
  };

  console.log(movies);

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <strong>Title</strong>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">
              <strong>Genre</strong>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">
              <strong>Stock</strong>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">
              <strong>Rate</strong>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right"></TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>

        {typeof movies === "object"
          ? movies.map((row) => (
              <TableBody key={row._id}>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.title}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.genre.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.numberInStock}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.dailyRentalRate}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">
                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      color="secondary"
                      onClick={() => handleDelete(row)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableBody>
            ))
          : null}
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default Movie;
```

**Problem**
the component is not re-rendering, it is only updating on the console.
**Explaination**

> Basically i am showing the movies on the table using material ui and
> react, i have display the content of the movies, but when i click  the
> delete button, it updates on the console but not on the UI means front
> end browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mutate your states. But with the delete you are.

React will not rerender, if the previous and current state are shallowly the same (AKA same obejct instance). You need to generate a new array without the movie that you want to delete.

For that, you can use the callback of setMovies and the filter function of arrays:

```
const handleDelete = (movie) => {
    setMovies(currentMovies => currentMovies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id));
  };
```

This will set the movies to a new array (filter generates a new array) and removes the selected one, since it will return false if the ids match and it will not be included in the returned array.

You also do not need the useEffect and just do it like this:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState(movieList);
```

Because this will only come into effect on the initial render and the useEffect does the exact same thing.